# How to share contents of a web page with social Networks and bookmarking them in on-line bookmark services?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, facebook, jquery-plugins

I'm Looking for a **free(or Open Source)** Sharing Script to put it in my content pages(I do ASP.net). I want to allow my visitors to share contents(ex: articles) in social networks like Facebook or on-line bookmark services like google bookmarks.
what's the best way to do that? i found [JQUERY SHARING](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sharing)(you can see demo [here](http://baladasusp.com/)) Plugin from the web. do you know any better choice!?
Please Share with me your experiences!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any script. [Addthis](http://www.addthis.com/) is your friend, my friend!
There are other services but this one is my favourite. The most important thing for you is to ensure your page has the correct meta and link tags corresponding to the type of media or content the page has.

Comment: I couldn't add more than one link but please also check "Sharing Rich Media" in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share to get a better idea of how to use meta and link tags to share your content.

Answer (score 0):

look up the number of articles listing the social bookmaking widgets and comparing them:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/sharing-widgets-for-websites/9249/

http://brightpinkstudio.com/pinkink/2010/01/social-bookmarking-widgets/

http://www.webanddesigners.com/top-15-social-bookmarking-plugins-for-wordpress

http://visionwidget.com/toolz/4-design/113-design-social-bookmarking.html